# Shell script can't use logical or with find command

Tags: shell

I have a script that deletes `*.log` or `*.txt` files either more than 10 MB or more than 15 days old. I wrote the code but cannot put `-or` between `*log` and `*txt`. How can I do that?

```
find . -iname "*.txt" -type f \( -mtime +15 -or -size +10000k \)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Indent code such as the `find` command by four spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think in terms of:

- `-iname "*.txt"` or `-iname "*.log"`
- and
- `-type f`
- and
- `-mtime +15` or `-size +10000k`

which translates to:

```
find . \( -iname "*.txt" -or -iname "*.log" \) -type f \( -mtime +15 -or -size +10000k \)
```

The default conjunction between terms is 'and' so there's no need for explicit `-and` operations.

Comment: Great this is what i need, i should give more time to syntax. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried -o?  Can you elaborate on the shell you're using?

Comment: GNU `find` allows [`-or`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Combining-Primaries-With-Operators) as synonym for `-o`.  This should really be a comment, though I recognize that you can't yet post comments.